# How to extract specific values from an array of strings in a dataframe column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with two columns (`words`, `numbers`) such that under words I have an array of Strings and numbers I have an array of Integers.

For example:

`words: ["hello","there","Everyone"] and numbers: [0,4,5]`

I would like to be able to get the words where the integer in numbers is not 0. thus in the above scenario only "there" and "Everyone" should be returned.

I am still a beginner in scala and spark and thus I tried filter, but how could I get inside the array? and how could I return the words ?

```
like df.filter(col("numbers") != 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply define the following UDF :

```
val myUDF = udf { (a : Seq[String], b : Seq[Int]) => 
  a.zip(b).filter(_._2 != 0).map(_._1) 
}
```

It zips together both arrays and filter based on the integer values.

```
df.select(myUDF($"words", $"numbers").as("words")).show
```

Returns the corresponding words in an array

```
+-----------------+
|            words|
+-----------------+
|[there, everyone]|
+-----------------+
```

If you want each word on a separate row you can use `explode` :

```
df.select(explode(myUDF($"words", $"numbers")).as("words")).show
```

Which results in

```
+--------+
|   words|
+--------+
|   there|
|everyone|
+--------+
```

Comment: Can you explain what this line "a.zip(b).filter(_._2 != 0).map(_._1)" really does ? how does the "_" work and what is zip to start with ?

Comment: Here is a good reference to start with : https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html